# How do I focus on one spec in jasmine.js?

Tags: jasmine

I have a bunch of failing specs from a rather large architectural change. I'd like to work on fixing them one by one by tagging each one with 'focus'.

Does jasmine.js have a feature like this? I swore I read at one point that it does but I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: @phil-pirozhkov's recent answer points out that this was introduced to Jaswine in v2.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a single test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132933/running-a-single-test-file)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can run a single spec by using the url for the spec

```
describe("MySpec", function() { 
  it('function 1', function() { 
    //... 
  }) 

  it('function 2', function() { 
    //... 
  } 

})
```

Now you can run just the whole spec by this url `http://localhost:8888?spec=MySpec` and a the first test with `http://localhost:8888?spec=MySpec+function+1`

Comment: Or just click on specs or individual tests on the results page

Comment: Awesome. Now, how do I get it to run this one: `describe("MySpec", ...)` and not this one: `describe("MySpec blah blah", ...)`? It seems to be doing a substring match.

Comment: describe.only is the correct answer if using jasmine 2.0, not sure about other versions.

Comment: `http://localhost:8888?spec=function+1` should work too (often don't need to specify MySpec)

Comment: @basarat this is what I was looking for. Couldn't find it in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: @davidjnelson where did you get this information? at least for jasmine >=2.4 its not working and it is not mentioned in the 2.0 docs

Answer (score 296):

When using Karma, you can enable only one test with `fit` or `fdescribe` (`iit` and `ddescribe` in Jasmine before 2.1).

---

This only runs `Spec1`:

```javascript
// or "ddescribe" in Jasmine prior 2.1
fdescribe('Spec1', function () {
    it('should do something', function () {
        // ...
    });
});

describe('Spec2', function () {
    it('should do something', function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

---

This only runs `testA`:

```javascript
describe('Spec1', function () {

    // or "iit" in Jasmine prior 2.1
    fit('testA', function () {
        // ...
    });

    it('testB', function () {
        // ...
    });

});
```

Comment: its a good tip, but currently it isn't in jasmine. this is allowed by test runners like karma. for more info read on: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/309

Comment: Jasmine 2.1 introduces this as `fdescribe` and `fit`: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/commit/ba0982d89f6d2a6523e505f062638a708ac0c25e#diff-3c2f8da4061d4489b0e5166eb05524c1R669

Comment: You'd have to be careful not to commit ii or dd specs. Easy to miss something like that.

Comment: @jameshfisher the question was asked in 2011. Also, `iit` and `ddescribe` are additions of Karma, not Jasmine.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks that mixing `xit` and `fit` into `it` are hard to read and error prone?

Comment: You can define git precommit hook (or build step) that does jshint validation, and define `describe`, `it` as allowed globals. Then jshint will complain if it finds `fdescribe`, `fit`, `xdescribe`, `xit` etc.

Comment: @Rimian: The Jasmine ESLint plugin will catch this, unless you explicitly disable it. If you use a hook that lints your code before committing, it drastically reduces the chance of accidentally committing it.

Answer (score 123):

[In core](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) since 2.1 with `fit` and `fdescribe`.

Comment: When I use 'fit' and run my tests in console using karma, I can see lot of skipped tests, but to see test errors I need to scroll to the top. When I run tests without 'fit' I do not have such problem, as I have errors summary at the bottom. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 27):

There are a few ways you can do it.

There is: Jasmine's feature **Focused Specs** (2.2): http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/focused_specs.html

Focusing specs will make it so that they are the only specs that run. Any spec declared with fit is focused.

```
describe("Focused specs", function() {
  fit("is focused and will run", function() {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('is not focused and will not run', function(){
    expect(true).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

However, I don't really like the idea of editing my tests (fit and fdescribe) to run them selectively. I prefer to use a test runner like [karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) which can filter out tests using a regular expression.

Here's an example using **grunt**.

```
$ grunt karma:dev watch --grep=mypattern
```

If you're using **gulp** (which is my favourite task runner), you can pass args into [gulp-karma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-karma) with yargs and match patterns by setting karma's config.

Kinda like this:

```
var Args = function(yargs) {
  var _match = yargs.m || yargs.match;
  var _file = yargs.f || yargs.file;
  return {
    match: function() { if (_match) { return {args: ['--grep', _match]} } }
  };
}(args.argv);


var Tasks = function() {
  var test = function() {
    return gulp.src(Files.testFiles)
      .pipe(karma({ configFile: 'karma.conf.js', client: Args.match()}))
      .on('error', function(err) { throw err; });
  };

  return {
    test: function() { return test() }
  }
}(Args);

gulp.task('default', ['build'], Tasks.test);
```

See my gist: https://gist.github.com/rimian/0f9b88266a0f63696f21

So now, I can run a single spec using the description:

My local test run: (Executed 1 of 14 (skipped 13))

```
gulp -m 'triggers the event when the API returns success'
[20:59:14] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[20:59:14] Starting 'clean'...
[20:59:14] Finished 'clean' after 2.25 ms
[20:59:14] Starting 'build'...
[20:59:14] Finished 'build' after 17 ms
[20:59:14] Starting 'default'...
[20:59:14] Starting Karma server...
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/spec/karma.conf.js" were excluded.
INFO [Chrome 42.0.2311 (Mac OS X 10.10.3)]: Connected on socket hivjQFvQbPdNT5Hje2x2 with id 44705181
Chrome 42.0.2311 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 1 of 14 (skipped 13) SUCCESS (0.012 secs / 0.009 secs)
[20:59:16] Finished 'default' after 2.08 s
```

Also see: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

Comment: I like your idea of using grunt to selectively run tests, but I wish gulp and karma config was more flexible, easier to extend, and easier to understand for that matter.

Answer (score 25):

For anyone stumbling upon this, a better approach, which you can set up from the code itself, is to use this plugin: https://github.com/davemo/jasmine-only

It allows you set the spec exclusivity right on the code like this:

```
describe.only("MySpec", function() { 
  it('function 1', function() { 
    //... 
  }) 

  it.only('function 2', function() { 
    //... 
  }
})
// This won't be run if there are specs using describe.only/ddescribe or it.only/iit
describe("Spec 2", function(){})
```

There has been a long discussion to get this added to Jasmine core, see: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/309

If you happen to be using Jasmine via Karma/Testacular you should already have access to `ddescribe()` and `iit()`

Comment: +1 for ddescribe and iit... This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is best... Also note that the new syntax is `fdescribe` and `fit` -- "f" meaning "focused". See also http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html

Answer (score 8):

You can create your all your specs up front but disable them with `xdescribe` and `xit` until you're ready to test them.

```
describe('BuckRogers', function () {
  it('shoots aliens', function () {
    // this will be tested
  });

  xit('rescues women', function () {
    // this won't
  });
});

// this whole function will be ignored
xdescribe('Alien', function () {
  it('dies when shot', function () {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most simplified answer with a practical example .Even in fdescribe you can run few it blocks using it. f means focus.

Also in a none fdescribe block which is just describe, you can select only specific it blocks by marking them as fit.

Please run the below code and observe the console log, also read the comments in the code.
Read this author's article it helps too . https://davidtang.io/2016/01/03/controlling-which-tests-run-in-jasmine.html

```
 //If you want to run few describe only add f so using focus those describe blocks and it's it block get run

  fdescribe("focus description i get run with all my it blocks ", function() {
    it("1 it in fdescribe get executed", function() {
        console.log("1 it in fdescribe get executed unless no fit within describe");

    });
    it("2 it in fdescribe get executed", function() {
        console.log("2 it in fdescribe get executed unless no fit within describe");

    });
    //but if you and fit in fdescribe block only the fit blocks get executed
    fit("3  only fit blocks in  fdescribe get executed", function() {
        console.log("If there is  a fit   in fdescribe only fit blocks  get executed");

    });
  });

  describe("none description i get skipped with all my it blocks ", function() {
        it("1 it in none describe get skipped", function() {
            console.log("1 it in none describe get skipped");

        });
        it("2 it in none describe get skipped", function() {
            console.log("2 it in none describe get skipped");
        });
//What happen if we had fit in a none fdescribe block will it get run ?   yes  
       fit("3 fit in none describe get executed too eventhough it;s just describe ", function() {
            console.log("3 fit in none describe get executed too");
        }); 
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

With stand-alone Jasmine(2.0.0), on the spec_runner.htlm, I could click a specific spec and focus on that one spec. I should have noticed this feature earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you've asked for but adding `iit` will test only that particular spec and ignore all others in the file, `ddescribe` works in the same way. So you can focus on a particular spec using `iit` or `ddescribe`