# dynamically skip protractor tests

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to skip protractor test dynamically?
I have scenarios where a user can select any specific test to perform. So, I want to execute only the tests user has specified and dependent tests, all other tests should be skipped.

I am using grunt-protractor-runner.

- protractor: 2.0
- Jasmine: 2.3

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527786/how-do-i-focus-on-one-spec-in-jasmine-js), you can specify a URL of a specific spec.
Otherwise you'd have to use the focused fdescribe/fit but you can't change it in runtime.
This is not related to Protractor but rather specific to Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

May be for you not actual. But it may be useful for other people. You can try to use the next construction:

```
it('your test', function(done)){

if('user action or result of user action'){
console.log("Test is skiped");
done();
}
//other test's code
...................
done(); 
}
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. `//other test's code' is still executed. But with your approach, you could simply `return` in the `if` branch to have an early exit without using the `done` function.