# How to run a single test file with Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Karma and Jasmine for testing my Angular JS code. I managed to run all the tests in my project using Karma, but if I try to run just a single file I'm getting the following error: `ReferenceError: describe is not defined`. Is it possible to run just a single test file and if yes then how?

P.S. I'm using Intellij IDEA.

Comment: anybody have an idea for this?

Comment: @JayKay what I do at the moment is just to comment out all the other test files that are included in karma.config.js and leave only my test file. I couldn't find a better solution yet.

Comment: thank you.... we can follow that until we found a solution. :)

Comment: @AntonBelev Hello, have you had any progress on this issue ?

Comment: Hi, @BiAiB, no, not really. I have not had the time to investigate it further.

Comment: **[Please upvote this issue: *Run single karma test*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173)**

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552729/karma-run-single-test/55525936#55525936

Answer (score 10):

Although it's not ideal, you can replace `describe` (and `it`) with `fdescribe` (and `fit`) so only those tests will be executed

On the other hand, `xdescribe` / `xit` excludes the tests from your suite

If you use Gulp, you can combine gulp-karma & yargs to pass in a pattern as argument.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696472/1782659

Comment: That's not an option : ) we have 3500+ tests. The idea is if you've just included a new test file and you want to run just this one. So far the only way is to comment out all the other test files from the karma.conf.js file.

Comment: the -f- option (focus) does just that
(don't forget to remove it again before you commit)

Comment: Blech. it.only and describe.only are so much more intuitive. This worked, however. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a [good post (JSGuy)](https://thejsguy.com/2016/01/03/controlling-which-tests-run-in-jasmine.html) about this functionality.

Comment: So far a remember there is a lint setting or something like that to avoid commit focussed test commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and you've inherited a suite of tests that are controlled by a task runner (e.g. gulp) and you are getting failures but are unsure which **file** is actually failing you can sanity check an individual file by running jasmine directly against it:

1.) Make sure you have jasmine installed (it may not be if wrapped inside your task runner configuration)

```
npm install jasmine
```

2.) Run jasmine against file:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine /path/to/my/spec/file.js
```

or

```
./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js /path/to/my/spec/file.js
```