# How to execute a single jasmine test file from karma?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing jasmine unit tests with karma as a test runner. I would like to be able to run the tests of a single file.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this :

```
karma run --specific-test="mySweetTest.js"
```

I know about fdescribe and fit, but that is simply an unacceptable solution to me.

Comment: Are you using Grunt, by chance? It's easy to set up a Grunt/Karma task with specific files.

Comment: We are using gulp for those sweet sweet tasks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150998/karma-running-a-single-test-file-from-command-line

Comment: You can use Jasmine directly, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591559/how-to-run-a-single-test-file-with-karma-jasmine/43227012#43227012