# How to run specific tests using Jasmine and Visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, visual-studio-code

I have started using Jasmine (not Karma yet) with Visual Studio Code.
Works nicely with the following config:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "jasmine",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my tests are building up I wanted to know if there was a way to just run a specific test or a tests within a specific file? At the moment all my tests are running which take a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way as from the cli would be the simplest option
(since Jasmine 2.1: [fit](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html), [fdescribe](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html))

See [How do I focus on one spec in jasmine.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527786/how-do-i-focus-on-one-spec-in-jasmine-js)