# Angular2 Unit test for specific components inside folder

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

Project scenario is like

- we have done so many new ui changes for the project.
- we want to update the test cases for all the components which has old ui test 
  cases.
- since it has old ui cases all the components is failing at once, so we are not 
  able to write and check unit testing for components simultaneously.

I am aware of fdescribe , fit , xdescribe and xit methods. if we use this mthods also we need to manually change in all components.

Is there any other way to achieve this. We want to run components in a specific folder alone. say folder name is formelemets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I focus on one spec in jasmine.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527786/how-do-i-focus-on-one-spec-in-jasmine-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fdescribe` instead of `describe` to focus a single test. This will skip all other describe blocks.

The same works for `it` and `fit`, just make sure to remove the `f` after your debugging session, to make sure that all tests are running in your CI